# How can I convert camel case name into underscore name using Eclipse/PyDev editor?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

How can I quickly convert **GenerateDocumentsFinishTask** into **generate_documents_finish_task** using Eclipse/PyDev editor?

What is keybinding for it - if it possible?

I often using such convention:

```
class_name = ClassName()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write:

`ClassName()`

And press `Ctrl+1` in that same line, you'll be prompted with an `Assign to local` which should do exactly what you want (considering you actually want to assign to a local).

Now, if you don't want to assign to a local but want to make that conversion, use the AnyEdit (http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) plugin (in AnyEdit, `Ctrl+Alt+B` then `Ctrl+Alt+K` can be used for that).